# Can we make a motor without a permanent magnet and with wireless energy transfer?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

If we could transfer energy wirelessly with 100% at short range. I think we could then use the energy to power an electromagnet from the [stator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stator#:%7E:text=The%20stator%20is%20the%20stationary,rotating%20component%20of%20the%20system.) side. So we wouldn't need a permanent magnet at all but I think it would still gain the same torque and efficiency as a conventional magnet motor.

But I can't find anyone who designs a motor this way. Is there any problem or disadvantage of this concept?

Edit: Sorry for not very clarified myself

What I have in mind is more like a common [DC motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor) than an [AC induction motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor), which would have both stator and rotor be a magnet pushing and pulling directly. I have an assumption that it would be more efficient and provide more torque than an induction motor, and more comparable with a DC motor.

What I have in mind is, the stator will have electromagnet windings and also contain magnetic induction coupling for transferring energy to the rotor. The rotor would have a coupling receiver that output energy to the magnet.

The design would be exactly the same as a DC motor. Maybe a design like a brush DC motor that replaces the brush with a wireless energy receiver and electronics controller. Or a brushless DC motor with only a wireless energy receiver.

Comment: I am not sure what your question involves, AC motors do not normally use permanent magnets.

Comment: maybe you just give us the design of this motor , start with the wireless energy transfer. otherwise make you concept more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a permanent magnet to make a motor: an induction motor needs no permanent magnet. If you can excite the stator with three-phase AC current that results in a rotating magnetic field, regardless of how the energy is supplied to the motor (wirelessly or otherwise), you can in principle make a functional induction motor. If you can't supply three-phase current to generate a rotating magnetic field, there are ways the traditional three-phase induction motor is modified to make single-phase induction motors, which can provide non-zero starting torque (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor#Starting)).

Some of the obvious questions are whether the energy transfer efficiency is high enough for this to be viable, whether this is useful if the range is short enough to achieve a sufficient efficiency, whether you need to convert the frequency used to transfer the energy to a lower frequency suitable for powering the motor, and whether you can transfer enough power to run a motor that meets your needs.

Comment: What I have in mind is, I don't really use wireless energy over the whole motor. I mean I would use it in the motor itself. The stator will be DC wired normally. But then the stator would also transmit energy to the rotor by induction coupling. The coupling will be nearly contact each other, as close as the rotor and stator is, so should be 100% ?